# change routing modules to send a response upon receipt of a message(request) on ONE simulator

Tags: dtn, one-simulator

How can i modify the routing modules on ONE simulator like epidemic ,prophet, spray and wait to send a response when the destination node receives a message?

Answer (score 0):

That kind of behavior is not part of the routing modules but part of applications. The routing modules only deal with trying to move messages toward the right destinations. The typical one-way messages you can create with the [Message Generators](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/wiki/README#routing-modules-and-message-creation) but for more complex behavior (e.g., request/reply) you need an application module.

There is already a [PingApplication](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/master/src/applications/PingApplication.java) that is usually sufficient for simple request/reply scenarios. If you need more complex application behaviour, making a new application based on the PingApplication is probably the best way forward.